# Web scraping VBA - Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

The code below extracts data from one web page - I emulate search, select all results from the list and when the list appears (42000 items) I loop through these items.

I get an id value from their href to create a proper link (example `href` is `href="javascript:NeuFenster('rb_id=570964&land_abk=bw'`, so I don't want any JS interaction while I can just create working links). Then I navigate to this link and extract whole text from last table row.

The main reason that I post this code is a memory issue. From all my testing here is what happens:

- `iexplore.exe` process starts for the main result page, with a helper 32 bit `iexplore.exe` *32;
- memory used by `iexplore.exe` *32 increases up to 308 MB and when result page is fully loaded, it remains +/- 2MB constant through whole extraction process;
- when a popup window (subpage for each result) is open, another `iexplore.exe` *32 opens, but unlike in the previous process, its memory usage never stops increasing, despite `PopUpWindow.Quit` and `set PopupWindow = nothing`;
- a third `iexplore.exe` process starts once first pop-up window is open, it has a constant memory usage around 24 MB. I have a problem understanding why such process appears at all;
- each time I have scraped around 6000 elements, IE automation error appears. I have concluded that maybe it's because at this point all `iexplore.exe` *32 processes together consume around 500MB of memory, maybe it's some limit.
- when I run this macro on other old PC, which has hardly any free RAM, automation errors appear usually around 10 times faster and therefore using this macro is impossible on that PC.

Is there any way to stop this increasing memory usage? Maybe I should set `IHTMLElement` objects to nothing as well?

Are there any other things which could be upgrade efficiency / transparency of the code (apart from moving code to a module, applying multithreading and using XML)?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement, htmlele2 As IHTMLElement
Dim ie As Object, PopupWindow As Object
Dim Link As String, LinkID As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim TimeCount As Double

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("results")

With ws

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Link = "https://www.handelsregisterbekanntmachungen.de/?aktion=suche#Ergebnis"
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate Link
'ie.Visible = True

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

'click on search button, search criteria are default
For Each htmlele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Value = "Suche starten" Then
        htmlele.Click

        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Exit For

    End If
Next htmlele

'find the "big" dropdown list with > 100 items, choose "all" and fire on change event to get all results listed
For Each htmlele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
    If htmlele.Children.Length > 100 Then
        htmlele.Value = "all"
        htmlele.selectedIndex = htmlele.Children.Length - 1
        htmlele.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Exit For
    End If
Next htmlele

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

i = 1

'TimeCount = Timer

For Each htmlele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(htmlele.href, "javascript:NeuFenster") <> 0 Then
        If htmlele.textContent <> vbNullString Then
            i = i + 1

            LinkID = Mid(htmlele.href, InStr(htmlele.href, "id=") + 3, 6)
            Link = "https://www.handelsregisterbekanntmachungen.de/skripte/hrb.php?rb_id=" & LinkID & "&land_abk=bw"

            Set PopupWindow = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            PopupWindow.Navigate Link
            'PopupWindow.Visible = True

            Do Until PopupWindow.ReadyState = 4 And PopupWindow.Busy = False
                DoEvents
            Loop

            For Each htmlele2 In PopupWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
                .Range("a" & i).Value = htmlele2.Children(htmlele2.Children.Length - 1).textContent
            Next htmlele2

            PopupWindow.Quit
            Set PopupWindow = Nothing

            'update status bar every 100 items
            If i Mod 100 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = i

        End If
    End If
Next htmlele

End With

ie.Quit

'Debug.Print Timer - TimeCount

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: The pop-up you create for each individual case has no scripts--it's vanilla HTML.  Rather than using a second IE process, you may want to look into XMLHTTP.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to learn next. Still some pop up pages which I have encountered had scripts and for them I must find a solution to this memory problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of work for a little button `Click` handler: your `UserForm` is running the show, it's doing much more than just collecting user input - it *is* the program. This is a design pattern known as "Smart UI", where the whole application logic is implemented in the UI. That's good for prototyping, but quickly becomes an unmaintainable tangle of globals and click handlers with hundreds of lines of code and countless responsibilities; you'll want to take a look at [UserForm best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms#t=201610021524374149052) on SO Documentation to see how you can separate *presentation* concerns from the actual *application logic*.

So I'll pretend that code isn't in some click handler and actually a specialized method of some dedicated class module. But how *specialized* is it?

By dividing the procedure into multiple smaller ones *that do one thing*, you will gain in maintainability, and more importantly you will be reducing your objects' scopes.

In VBA the smallest possible scope is at procedure level. This means an object reference doesn't go out of scope until a procedure exits; if in theory setting a reference to `Nothing` destroys it, in practice if it's still used in the same scope, then it's still in scope.

By splitting up your logic in smaller scopes you give much clearer clues to the VBA runtime: objects don't need to be set to `Nothing` when they only ever live long enough to do their thing; in fact an object going out of scope is the only reliable way to make sure VBA cleans it up properly. `PopupWindow` doesn't belong in the same scope as `ie`.

Then there's the separation of concerns: *collecting inputs* (reading the scraped data) doesn't belong in the same procedure as *outputting results* (writing to some target worksheet).

There should be a function responsible for collecting the data, stuffing it into an array and returning that array to the caller; then another procedure takes that array and a given `Worksheet` object, and writes all results in one single operarion, no looping is necessary. By separating inputs from outputs you'll be *specializing* each procedure, making the whole thing more performant. You don't need `ScreenUpdating` turned off while you're collecting the data - you could use the `Application.StatusBar` to update some progress indicator as you go (say once every 5%), and that wouldn't affect performance much - what's costing you here is the fact that you're writing to individual cells in a nested loop.

Extract procedures from each loop body, reduce variables/objects' scopes as much as possible, and separate concerns - you'll gain performance, lose memory footprint, and end up with overall more maintainable code.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I will definitely separate the code into more scopes and give the feedback about how the memory behaves. As for arrays, I am quite hesitant in this particular case - outputting to cells lets me preserve all data in worksheet in case of disconnects or an error while interacting with website. Without multi-threading performance hit is almost none, but I will probably try at least creating arrays for every single row with data.

Comment: VBA/COM is single-threaded, you can't write multithreaded code in VBA. If you know the size of the ouptut 2D array from the start, you can dimension it once, populate it, and dump it onto the worksheet in one, single, instantaneous write operation; you're not going to "lose" any of the collected data if you handle runtime errors properly.

Comment: I can't mullti-thread in VBA, but I can use VBA to create many VB script files that will do the work.

Comment: Unfortunately creating more scopes - Public Subs - especially separating the one responsible for creating PopupWindow instances didn't resolve memory problem, it's all the same.